# How to calculate time diff and get the result in time format

Tags: r, dplyr, data-science, tidyverse

I want diff time in time for the table below

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 30/07/2021 23:58 | 30/07/2021 23:59 |
| 30/07/2021 23:58 | 30/07/2021 23:58 |
| 30/07/2021 23:58 | 30/07/2021 23:58 |
| 30/07/2021 23:58 | 30/07/2021 23:58 |
| 30/07/2021 23:58 | 30/07/2021 23:58 |
| 30/07/2021 23:57 | 30/07/2021 23:58 |
| 30/07/2021 23:57 | 30/07/2021 23:58 |
| 30/07/2021 23:57 | 30/07/2021 23:58 |

all the methods have tried keep giving results like 1sec, but I want the result in time format like 00:00:02

this is the method I've tried below
`` processing_time =difftime(time1 = Date , time2 = `Updated Time`, units = "secs") ``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you have this data in a data.frame but have not yet converted the date-time values to POSIXct class. The this might succeed:

```
dat$processing_time <- with(dat, difftime( as.POSIXct(B, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") , 
                                           as.POSIXct(A, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")))

> dat
                 A                B processing_time
1 30/07/2021 23:58 30/07/2021 23:59         60 secs
2 30/07/2021 23:58 30/07/2021 23:58          0 secs
3 30/07/2021 23:58 30/07/2021 23:58          0 secs
4 30/07/2021 23:58 30/07/2021 23:58          0 secs
5 30/07/2021 23:58 30/07/2021 23:58          0 secs
6 30/07/2021 23:57 30/07/2021 23:58         60 secs
7 30/07/2021 23:57 30/07/2021 23:58         60 secs
8 30/07/2021 23:57 30/07/2021 23:58         60 secs
```

Then you need to get that data in a form that format.POSIXt will respect:

Perhaps:

```
 format(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date())+dat$processing_time, "%H:%M:%S")
```

You might need to add or subtract hours to get that to appear correct since you probably did as I did and didn't enter a timezone so GMT was assumed.